# Redirect different pages after form submit, based on URL sequence

Tags: php, forms, redirect, submit, sequence

I have a form page called *form.php* 
which will submit data to *send.php*
with the general form format:

```
<form action="send.php" method="post">
```

I'd like to make it more advanced with redirect function after submission, based on URL sequence.

**Example plot:**

If someone submit data from *form.php?redirect=home.php*, 
he will be redirected to *home.php* after submitting data

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can include at the end of send.php, a redirection to the value in form.php?redirect=XXXXXX

something like:

```
    <?php
    $url=$_GET["redirect"];
      header("Location: $url");
    ?>
```